# Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on null

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to include function "overlay" from config.php into other php pages.

Index.php:

```
<?php include("./config/config.php");
over_lay(); ?>
//// html code ////
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function connect() on null in ...\config\config.php on line 182
```

Part of config.php:

```
include("./config/mysql.php");
function over_lay()
{
$mysqli->connect();
?>
//// html code with partly mysqli requests ////
<?php
  $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

And finally mysql.php:

```
<?php
function connect() 
{
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","database_name");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
return $mysqli;
}
?>
```

I'm testing this on OpenServer and of course I do have the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function inside your over_lay

```
include("./config/mysql.php");
function over_lay()
{
    $mysqli = connect();
     ?>
     //// html code with partly mysqli requests ////
     <?php
     $mysqli->close();
 }
```

**Update**
I simply changed

`$mysqli->connect();`

to

`$mysqli = connect();`

Comment: what does your https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp reference have anything to do with the question/answer?

Comment: good point i thought his connection was messed up too. thanks for pointing out

Comment: simply i think the error is here `$mysqli->connect();`

Comment: Looks like it worked for me. At different sites I saw $mysql->connect(); and it worked there. Why it isn't working here?

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake, there was no ->. Thanks a lot.